# How to Edit a contributed module

Tags: 7

I am using the Feedback Module, and I need to add an email field to the feedback form. How can I make the necessary edits to the Feedback Module in such a way that they stay when the module is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chances G is right but in cases that you need to make a new feature or make a change that you can't handle via Drupal's hook system you should [create a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484) and submit it to the community.

Comment: I think this is more of what I need. Since to make my email field work on the form I had to add code in in at least a dozen places. 

So even though what I did might not be used by everyone using the module it is still worth it to submit it as a patch?

Comment: If it is something that you think is specific to you and won't work for everyone then it is better to create a custom hook in the contributed module and patch that. Now in your custom module you should be able to use your new hook.  If it something as simple as adding an email field I feel like @Chances G might be right in using hook_form_alter() to add an email field.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Answer (score 4):

You should never edit core or contributed modules if it can be helped (which it almost always can).  I haven't used Feedback, but the general Drupal way of extending forms is to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) from your own custom module.

Basically create a simple module.  All it needs is a mymodule.info file and a mymodule.php file inside of a folder in /sites/all/modules. Here is some [more info](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360) on creating a module.

Then in your mymodule.php file, add a function that looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FEEDBACK_MODULE_FORMID') {
    $form['custom_email'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Email',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = '_mymodule_feedback_form_submit';
  }
}
```

This will add a new field to the form, and register a submit callback for the form.

Finally write the `_mymodule_feedback_form_submit` function to actually do something with the value when the form is submitted.